# Understanding memory allocation

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-memory

I am trying to understand how memory is allocated by the `std::list` data structure. I made a small test program

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>

class MyClass
{
public:

 MyClass();
~MyClass(){}

private:
std::list<unsigned char> numlist;
};

MyClass::MyClass()
{
numlist.push_back(1);
}

int main()
{ 

 MyClass c; // instantiate
}
```

I ran the above snippet in valgrind

```
$valgrind --leak-check=full ./indepth 
==32330== HEAP SUMMARY:
==32330==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==32330==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 24 bytes allocated
```

Please help me to understand why 24 bytes were allocated here.

Comment: Check your sample without `#include <iostream>`. Also note that `MyClass c;` goes to the stack and no dynamic allocation is made in first place. I'd assume that statement will be optimized away at least.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - the constructor of `MyClass` allocates memory through the call to `list::push_back`.

Comment: @PeteBecker Oops didn't spot that. But there shouldn't be allocated more than 1 byte, should it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ : `iostream` has nothing to do with the 24 bytes being allocated

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - depending on how the list is implemented, it allocatee 1 **node**, which would have two pointers and an `int` value.

Comment: @hAcKnRoCk So I assume you verified that? Just including `<iostream>` involves to create instances for `std::cout`, `std::cin` and `std::cerr`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes i verified it

Comment: `std::cout`, `std::cin` and `std::cerr` are not allocated on the heap

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing more about the particular compiler and it's options, it's hard to give a definitive answer. But the call to `push_back` will allocate a node for the list element that it creates, and that node will have two pointers (one for the next node and one for the previous), and an `int` that holds the stored value. To get details on the sizes of those parts, run this program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << sizeof(int*) << ", " << sizeof(unsigned char) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

That will tell you how big a pointer is and how big an `int` is.

Comment: The compiler is `gcc version 4.9.2 20150212 (Red Hat 4.9.2-6) (GCC) `. I compiled it using 
`g++ -std=c++11 -g indepth.cpp -o indepth`

Comment: Got it. So, the pointers are of size 8. So 2 pointers = 16 bytes+ 8 for the unsigned char (which is an integer type). Therefore, 24 bytes

Comment: @hAcKnRoCk - whoops, replace "int" in my answer with "unsigned char". That was a bit of carelessness on my part. An unsigned char is probably 1 byte, but the node size has probably been rounded up to a multiple of 8.

Comment: Yes Pete your answer helped me anyways. I got the point. edited int to unsigned char in your snippet

Comment: If I replace the `std::list<int>` by `std::list<string>` and push a single character, 55 bytes are allocated. Now, I am wondering where are the 39 bytes coming from.

Comment: @hAcKnRoCk Can't be sure, but if I was allocating storage for a string's internal buffer I wouldn't be doing it character by character. I'd allocate a reasonable sized chunk to reduce the frequency of reallocations. 40 bytes sounds reasonable to me.

Answer (score 2):

The exact size of every element in an `std::list` depends on the STL implementation, but normally it is implemented as **double linked list**, that means that every node (which represents the elements) requires at least 3 data members (**previous node**, **next node**, to implement the *double link list*, and the **data**).

In gcc implementation, the file **std_list.h** class `_List_node` contains the definition of this node. 2 pointers (2 * 4 bytes in 32bits or 2 * 8 bytes in 64bits) plus sizeof(data).

Additional to that, the list may have to maintain some other internal info like the size (since C++11 is mandated by the standard that `std::list::size()` is **O(1)**).

*Notes:*

**STL implementation** = **Standard Library implementation** (the implementation of the C++ Standard Library that came with the compiler or is configured to be used by the compiler)

- in the case of *gcc* is **libstdc++**
- in case of *clang* could be **libc++** (the clang implementation) or **libstdc++** (the gcc implementation)
- in case of *VC++*, their internal implementation (by **Dinkumware**).

There's other STL implementation like **STLPort**, etc... And these details are implementation dependent. The only way to be sure is looking the code of the specific version of the STL implementation and the exact size could change any time.

Comment: Fantastic answer. Could you edit explain a bit more the "exact size of every element in an std::list depend of the STL implementation". Why? exact size of every element or you meant type?

Answer (score 1):

> Please help me to understand why 24 bytes were allocated here.

Such details are implementation specific, so the definitive answer lies in the source code or documentation of your compiler and standard library. The memory use can very well differ in another implementation.

But, it's possible to make an educated guess based on a trivial implementation of a doubly linked list: The number of nodes cannot be known in general at compile time, so they'll probably need to be allocated dynamically. A node should have a pointer to next and previous node, and the stored data. That's 1 `int` and 2 pointers. In a particular architecture it's quite possible that the size of pointers happens to be 8 bytes. `int` also typically fits in 8 bytes but even if it's smaller, the node would have to be padded to nearest 8 byte boundary to satisfy the alignment requirement of the pointers. That makes 8*3 = 24 bytes for this imaginary trivial implementation. The real implementation used by your standard library might be similar.

Answer (score 0):

The container `std::list` is a linked list, so it allocates nodes that contains not only your element, but two pointers: one pointer to the next node and one pointer to the previous.

If you want a more memory efficient container, consider using `std::vector` and pre-allocate memory with the `std::vector::reserve` function.

Comment: Vector is more memory and time efficient, a lot of the time. A linked list is by its nature a scattered beast, making for some horrific losses to cache misses and possible optimizations based on prediction. Read more here: https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/06/stroustrup-lists